# Using Google AND Outlook.com to handle my domain emails

Tags: email, gmail, outlook.com

This is a rather simple question for experts in the mail server area.

I purchased a custom domain and I would like to have two mail service providers to handle my emails. Google.com and Outlook.com because some of my *users* are used to GMail and others to Outlook interface and I'd like to keep them using what they like.

**Is it possible to setup MX records with my registrar that particular emails will go to Outlook servers and others to Google's?**

How can I set this up? Is it possible?

Comment: You'll find it easier to tell your users to get used to a different interface!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Its not possible, as an MX record binds to a domain name, not a user.

You would need to get 1 provider accepting all your emails and then forwarding them on, as appropriate to the second provider.